# how to return dataset in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dataset, return

This is my class code. I want to return the dataset from the procedure _return()
I want to return this to another form where I called the procedure.
What return type should I use? How to implement it?

```
public class Class1
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2005;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\krish\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\TRS\App_Data\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public void _return(String qry)
    {
        con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
        da.Fill(ds, "details");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can mention function return type `DataSet` and simply return that `DataSet`

```
public DataSet _return(String qry)
{
    con.Open();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
    da.Fill(ds, "details");
    con.Close();
    return ds;

}
```